# Select a row in listview

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I am web developer , working on a part of my project developed in WinForms. So my question could be a basic one. Try to bear with it.

I have two list views on my page and a remove button that works for both.

Problems.

1. I am not able to select a row in both the list view when I run my program, may be some property needed for it?
2. If I am able to select the row I want to detect which list view item has been selected, so how would I do that?
3. I have three columns and have bound the data by using the code below.

   ```
       listView1.Columns.Add("ID",20);
       listView1.Columns.Add("Name",40);
       listView1.Columns.Add("Mobile",40);


       foreach (var item in dataList)
       {
           newItem = new ListViewItem();
           newItem.SubItems.Add(item.ID.ToString());
           newItem.SubItems.Add(item.Name);
           newItem.SubItems.Add(item.Mobile.ToString());
           listView1.Items.Add(newItem);   
       }
   ```

but the `ID` column is left blank and the data starts to bind in these sense.

```
ID Name Mobile
   1    abc
   2    xyz
```

So how do I properly show the data?

4. Lastly I want to use my `ID` column to delete the data.  So if I give `width=0`, is this the best way to hide a column?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. See [ListView.FullRowSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect.aspx) property.
2. See [ListView.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx) property. Note, that by default `ListView` allows multiselection.
3. Set item text via constructor: `newItem = new ListViewItem(item.ID.ToString());`, then add rest of subitems (except of `item.ID`).
4. If you want to delete the column, just remove it from the columns collection.

Comment: thanks for your answer. point no 1,3 has been resolved.on point no 2. i need some inputs , this is what I am doing  if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    
                    //how to extract the value of hidden column ie.ID
                    //multi select option is set to be false
                }

            }

Comment: @ankur: do not store value, which you don't want to display in *view* item. If you just want to use `item.ID` later without displaying it, bind `ListViewItem` with data item: `newItem.Tag = item`. Later you can get it with `((YourDataItemType)item.Tag).ID`.

Comment: the approach with tags was pretty gud, but i am not able to get the value. also I have gone through lot of examples of deleting the selected row with multiple columns nothing seems to do the trick. the id that I have kept hidden was actually used for same thing. so can you help me on this my code on delete button.foreach (ListViewItem item in listView2.SelectedItems)
                    {
                        var id = ((int)item.Tag).ID;// this line give error
                        listView2.Items.Remove(item);
                        
                    }

Comment: @ankur: I'm confusing about what do you want to achieve. Do you want to delete selected items? If so, why don't you just remove them from items collection?

Comment: I want to remove the selected row from the list-view as well delete the  same row from database. so for achieving the latter one I need the id of the selected row that I have kept in "tag". I have wrote the code  of removing the selected row only thing is I want the tag value of selected item ie "ID".

Comment: @ankur: I see. If you will put in `Tag` *value* of `item.ID` (`newItem.Tag = item.ID`), then you could get it back such a way: `var id = (int)item.Tag;` If you will put the whole data item (`newItem.Tag = item`), then you could get `ID` this way: `((YourDataItemType)item.Tag).ID`, where `YourDataItemType` is a type of data item object, not a type of any of its properties.

Answer (score 1):

Set
listView1.Items[index].Selected=true;

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Be cautious about answering 8 year old questions which have confirmed answers.  If your answer truely adds value (like a recent update to APIs), go for it but otherwise, best to leave them answered as-is.