# User select list view row

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to make a form of list view where the user can select an entire row with one click of an element. Is it possible to do this?

An example of what I need, the table below represents the list view to the user:

```
   Name     |                 Question                |  QID
--------------------------------------------------------------
John Doe      How do I access this...                     1
Johan Doe     I need help with this argument...           2
John Doe      Follow up question: is it possible...       3
```

When the user clicks on John Doe's first question, the entire row should then become selected, for use with listView.SelectedItems[x].

If i was unclear about my question, please tell me. Any responses are welcome, thank you.

Comment: this might be useful -->  [Select a row in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596500/select-a-row-in-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the `ListView` has a property named `FullRowSelect` that you can set to `true` to achieve what you need. Here is some important info from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The FullRowSelect property has no effect unless the View property of the ListView control is set to Details. The FullRowSelect property is typically used when a ListView displays items with many subitems and it is important to be able to see selected items when the item text is not visible due to horizontal scrolling of the control's contents.