# Highlight Only Selected Subitem C#

Tags: c#, listview

I am using a listview. It has 4 columns and 64 rows. When mouse clicked for a subitem,if "FullRowSelect" is actived, all rows turn highlight. If ""FullRowSelect" is NOT actived, i can select only items, not subitems. How can highligt only selected subitems when mouse clicked?

Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3eHG.png)

Comment: There is a true solution for this.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/12596500/11998655

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74688162/is-select-the-one-subitem-without-full-row-possible-c-sharp